# YAML ADO pipeline - conditional inputs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm aware that parameters cannot be optional. I'm building a pipeline with multiple stages, but I wanted to be able to run only certain stages at times.

- Imagine a pipeline which deploys 5 things for a client
- Each thing requires 10 input parameters.
- I want to be able to sometimes just deploy 3 of those things, as not all clients will need all 5

Using parameters I can't just leave them blank and then use the logic *IF PARAMETER IS EMPTY, SKIP STAGE*. I could ask which resources to deploy in input, but then I can't ask again "hey based on the 3 you chose, I now need these 30 values".

Is there any way around this? Any other ideas on how to design something with the above requirements?

Something that occurred to me:

- Have a "config" file which says which resources get deployed and has the input values
- This would require someone to write this up in JSON or whatever and put it into a repo
- Pipeline would ask for a file name only, then grab the file, expand it and retrieve the inputs and run whatever stages based on this

This isn't very user friendly but could work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just occurred to me, could I use default values for all parameters as ' ' (empty) and therefore you could fill only the ones you needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you need to input the related parameters according to the selected stages.

I am afraid that there is no direct way can achieve your requirements.

Parameter assignment and stage manual selection are done at the same time, so it is not possible to set the required parameters based on the manually selected stage.

At the same time, the parameter value is not able to set as empty when running the pipeline. The value is required.

> Is there any way around this? Any other ideas on how to design something with the above requirements?

I suggest that you can run the Pipeline stage based on the parameters value.

For the parameters value, you can set them to specific values(e.g. None) Then you can use [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) to check if the stage needs to be run.

Here is YAML example:

```
parameters:
- name: test3
  displayName: Run Tests?
  default: 'None'
- name: test
  displayName: Run Tests?
  type: string
  default: 'None'
- name: test1
  displayName: Run Tests?
  type: string
  default: 'None'
- name: test2
  displayName: Run Tests?
  type: string
  default: 'None'

stages:
  - ${{ if and(ne(parameters.test3, 'None'), ne(parameters.test, 'None')) }}:
    - stage: stage1
      jobs:
      - job: test1
        steps:
        - script: echo "1"
  - ${{ if and(ne(parameters.test1, 'None'), ne(parameters.test2, 'None')) }}:
    - stage: stage2
      jobs:
      - job: test2
        steps:
        - script: echo "1"
```

When the related parameters value is none, the stage will skip. Or if we input related values to all parameters, it will run the  corresponding stage.

Comment: Thanks, I used a similar solution with a default value a condition on the stages.